# do-while loop and window.alert message

Tags: javascript, html, do-while

Good evening guys.

I would like your help with the following topic.
I have these lines of code:

```
<script>
    function save3() {
        var pn = 4;
        var flag = true;
        do {
            var selection = window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!");
            if (selection == (/^[0-9.,]+$/)) {
                flag = false;
                window.alert("ok");
            }
        } while (flag != false);
        $("#user_id").val(selection)
        //$("#user_id").val(prompt("Give the User Id:"))
        do {
            var selection2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the Book Id:", "Type a number!"), 10);
        } while (isNaN(selection2));
        $("#book_id").val(selection2)
        //$("#book_id").val(prompt("Give the Book Id:"))
        do {
            var selection3 = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the Game Id:", "Type a number!"), 10);
        } while (isNaN(selection3));
        $("#game_id").val(selection3)
        //$("#game_id").val(prompt("Give the Game Id:"))
        $("#site_id").val(pn)
    }

    function load2() {

    }
</script>
```

My question maybe is simple for you, but i can't figure out the solution.
I want a user to insert to the window.prompt box a value. If value is a number. i want to display a message to the user "correct". If a value is a letter or something else, i want to display a message "try again" and the loop should be executed again.

Can you provide me with some help? I think that i have done a part of what i want...

Comment: What is not working with your code above? Where is flag defined?

Comment: @epascarello i've posted again my full code. I think that it is inserted in an infinitive loop..but im newbie and i dont know for sure..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (selection == (/^[0-9.,]+$/)){
```

That is not how you use a regular expression. You need to use [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@match) or [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```
if (selection && selection.match(/^[0-9.,]+$/))
if (selection && /^[0-9.,]+$/.test(selection))
```

Comment: yes!! you have right! Now it is working like a charm. Thank you so much. Accepted answear.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help guys.

Here is my working solution:

```
<script>
    function save3() {
      var pn = 4; 
      var flag1 = true;
      do{
        var selection = window.prompt("Give the User Id:", "Type a number!");
            if ( /^[0-9]+$/.test(selection)) {
            flag1=false;
            window.alert("ok");
            }
        }while(flag1!=false);
    $("#user_id").val(selection)
      //$("#user_id").val(prompt("Give the User Id:"))

      var flag2 = true;
      do{
        var selection2 = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the Book Id:", "Type a number!"));
        if ( /^[0-9]+$/.test(selection2)) {
            flag2=false;
            window.alert("ok");
            }
        }while(flag2!=false);
    $("#book_id").val(selection2)
      //$("#book_id").val(prompt("Give the Book Id:"))

      var flag3= true;
      do{
        var selection3 = parseInt(window.prompt("Give the Game Id:", "Type a number!"));
        if ( /^[0-9]+$/.test(selection3)) {
            flag3=false;
            window.alert("ok");
            }
        }while(flag3!=false);
    $("#game_id").val(selection3)
      //$("#game_id").val(prompt("Give the Game Id:"))

      $("#site_id").val(pn)
    }
    function load2() {

    }

  </script>
```